# OleInitialization in Delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

Are there any downsides to adding OleInitialization calls to the main form of a project? eg:

```
initialization
  OleInitialize(nil);
finalization
  oleuninitialize;
```

(added to the main form of the application) appears to be a necessary addition to allow copying selected text from a TWebBrowser (on another form) to the clipboard. But I'm wondering if there are any unexpected consequences I might face in my program based on whether or not I add those lines? MSDN's description of [OleInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates there are effects on the threading/concurrency model, but I don't totally understand the significance of those differences.

Comment: To answer this you must know if you use any other COM related stuff in your application. If you not use components/libraries that require a different concurrent model feel free to add the initialization and finalization the way you show in your question. If you don't know, well, you can go deep in your project and check, or you can just try it and look for errors or misbehavior in your exe.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I'd say, TWebBrowser initialises COM on its own, therefore clipboard failure is a sign of conflict.

Comment: TWebBrowser should not initialise COM. The well-known rule is that apps rather than components have to initialise COM.

Comment: @jessica Normally COM is initialized when your app's .dpr file executes Application.Initialize. Why is that not happening for you?

Comment: Perhaps the .dpr file is missing some code to initialize COM? it looks like it's been customized a bit to prevent multiple instances and manually creates the main form with Application.CreateForm(..). It does call Application.Initialize before that a couple lines, but when I started looking into why the embedded browser right-click menu copy option wasn't working, adding com initialization code to the main form (which isn't the form my TWebBrowser is on) was the top suggestion. I don't think anything else is using COM, unless that's how ShellExecute works or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an article from Embarcadero that confirms that you do need to call OleInitialize: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20468

There's no problem calling it the way you do. That is how it is meant to be done.